# How to read ZIP file in an S3 bucket with a Python Lambda function?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, zip

I'm creating a backend function so that users of App A can import their details to App B. The flow is like this:

1. User uploads a zip file on the website. This zip contains csv files.
2. This zip file flows into S3.
3. Once in S3, it triggers a Lambda function.
4. The Lambda function then picks the zip file and starts processing the data inside the csv files.

I've completed Step 1,2 and 3. But in 4, the Lambda function is not able to read/process the file.

**The python file works fine on my local device, so I think the issue is that it is not able to "get" the object from S3 correctly and so the read_zip doesn't work.**

Relevant code below:

```
import <relevant libs>

s3Client = boto3.client('s3')

def lambda_handler(event,context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    filename = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    #tried printing these, displaying correctly

    #response = s3Client.get_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=filename)
    
    usefile = 'https://' + bucket + '.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/' + filename
    print(usefile)
    #printing correct filename

    def read_csv(file):
        to_return = []

        reader = csv.DictReader(TextIOWrapper(file, 'utf-8'))
        for row in reader:
            to_return.append(row)
        return to_return


    def read_zip(usefile):
        with ZipFile(usefile, 'r') as APPA_file:
            with APPA_file.open("file1.csv", mode='r') as f:
                file1 = read_csv(f)
            with APPA_file.open("file2.csv", mode='r') as f:
                file2 = read_csv(f)

        return file1, file2


    def get_APPB_url(APPA_uri):
        resp = requests.get(APPA_uri)
        if resp.status_code != 200:
            return None

        # extract the APPB url
        re_match = re.findall('href="(https://www.X.org/.+/)"', resp.text)
        if not re_match:
            return None
        print(resp.text)
        return re_match[0]


    def rate_on_APPB(APPB_url, rating):
        re_match = re.findall('X.org/(.+)/', APPB_url)
        if not re_match:
            return None


        

        APPB_id = re_match[0]
        req_body = {
            "query": <query used>,
            "operationName": "<xyz>",
            "variables": <variables>
        }
        headers = {
            "content-type": "application/json",
            "x-hasura-admin-secret": "XXX"
        }

        resp = requests.post("XXX", json=req_body, headers=headers)

        if resp.status_code != 200:
            raise ValueError(f"Hasura query failed. Code: {resp.status_code}")
        else: print(APPB_id)

        json_resp = resp.json()
        if 'errors' in json_resp and len(json_resp['errors']) > 0:
            first_error_msg = json_resp['errors'][0]['message']

            if 'Authentication' in first_error_msg:
                print(f"Failed to authenticate with cookie")
                exit(1)
            else:
                raise ValueError(first_error_msg)


    def APPA_to_APPB(APPA_dict):
        APPB_url = get_APPB_url(APPA_dict['APPA URI'])
        if APPB_url is None:
            raise ValueError("Cannot find APPB title")
        rate_on_APPB(APPB_url, int(float(APPA_dict['Rating']) * 2))

    def main():

        file1, file2 = read_zip(usefile)

        success = []
        errors = []

        with tqdm(total=len(file1)) as pbar:
            with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
                future_to_url = {
                    executor.submit(APPA_to_APPB, APPA_dict): APPA_dict for APPA_dict in file1
                }
                try:
                    for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(future_to_url):
                        APPA_dict = future_to_url[future]
                        pbar.update(1)
                        try:
                            success.append(future.result())
                        except Exception as e:
                            errors.append({"APPA_dict": APPA_dict, "error": e})
                except KeyboardInterrupt:
                    executor._threads.clear()
                    concurrent.futures.thread._threads_queues.clear()

        print(f"Successfully rated: {len(success)} ")
        print(f"{len(errors)} Errors")
        for error in errors:
            print(f"\t{error['APPA_dict']['Name']} ({error['APPA_dict']['Year']}): {error['error']}")


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

CloudWatch log basically says Event started and ended successfully, nothing else. I was able to verify that the trigger was working fine by printing the file name and it appears in the log. But that's about it.

Comment: I would start with the basics.  That you are guessing what is wrong suggests that you are not seeing what your function is outputting to stdout and stderr.  Are you looking at the cloudwatch log stream for the lambda or for s3?  If your code is failing, you should see something in the logs.  I would start with making sure that you are able to see the output of your function.  Put some print statements in your code and make sure that you see the results of them in the cloudwatch logs for the lambda.

Comment: As presented, your lambda handler does nothing with the object retrieved from S3.  Assuming this is a partial example, please post a [mre] so we can help you diagnose what's failing.

Comment: Your program is defining the `read_zip()` and `read_csv()` functions, but it is never calling them. In fact, the program does nothing after calling `get_object()`.

Comment: Apologies, didn't realize that I hadn't posted that. Have updated the code with the full block, hope this provides context.

Comment: Are you aware that when run in a Lambda _only_ the `lambda_handler` executes (along with globals)?  Even assuming you fix the indention is here, all this will do as a Lambda is print out the S3 Key from the event.